# ¿Cómo crear una instancia de un servicio con base en un parámetro?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, wcf

Tengo dos servicios WCF iguales y que presentan los mismos contratos, instalados en dos servidores diferentes (`Deleg_A` y `Deleg_B`). Por otro lado tengo una aplicación que consume estos servicios y los tiene referenciados como `srvDeleg_A` y `srvDeleg_B`, respectivamente.

En esta aplicación tengo una clase que la usaré a modo de *proxy* para consumir un servicio u otro con base en un parámetro en el constructor.

```
public class ServFacturacion
{
   private string servicioDeleg;
   public ServFacturacion(string param)
   {
       if (param == "A") 
          servicioDeleg = "A";
       else
          servicioDeleg = "B";    
   }

   //Uno de los contratos que expone el servicio
   public List<Factura_poco> GetFacturasDia(DateTime fecha)
   {
      //Aquí se instancia el servicio para consumirlo, sería algo así:
      MiAplicacion.srvDeleg_A.MiServicio cliente = new MiAplicacion.srvDeleg_A.MiServicio();
      //o ...
      MiAplicacion.srvDeleg_B.MiServicio cliente = new MiAplicacion.srvDeleg_B.MiServicio();

      //Una vez instanciado el que corresponda en base al parámetro, lo utilizo
      var resultado = cliente.ElContratoQueSea().....
      ...
   }
}
```

Lo que yo quiero es que en base al parámetro del constructor, crear una instancia del servicio `A` o el `B`.

Imagino que debe poder hacerse, aunque no se me ocurre ninguna forma "elegante" de hacerlo.

Comment: Los servicios heredan de una interfaz comun?

Comment: Te refieres a algo asi como el [patrón de inyección de dependencias?](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_de_dependencias)

Comment: "Los servicios heredan de una interfaz comun?" son idénticos, lo único es que están instalados en dos servidores diferentes, pero en la aplicación, el nombre que se les da al referenciarlos es diferente. No sé si con esto contesto a tu pregunta.

Comment: Pikoh, me miro este enlace, pero desconozco como funciona esto de la "inyección de depencencias". A mi cualquier forma de hacerlo (correctamente) me viene bien.

Comment: Entonces no entiendo el problema.. esta resuelto en tu codigo, en la funcion GetFacturasDias si sabes cual es el parametro que pasaste al constructor, haces el objeto cliente que corresponda y listo...

Comment: @Carlos el tema es demasiado amplio para explicarlo aqui. Pero creo que es patrón de diseño ese mas o menos lo que buscas. Te dejo otro enlace (en ingles) [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh323705(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: gbianchi, eso es justamente lo que no se hacer.

Answer (score 1):

No estoy entendiendo bien el problema, o ya esta resuelto.

Si los dos contratos son iguales, es lo mismo que querer conectarse a distintas bases de datos o leer distintos archivos:

```
public class ServFacturacion
{
   private string servicioDeleg;
   public ServFacturacion(string param)
   {
       //Mejor algo asi
       servicioDeleg = param;
   }

   //Uno de los contratos que expone el servicio
   public List<Factura_poco> GetFacturasDia(DateTime fecha)
   {
       //Como son los dos iguales, vale desde cualquiera de los dos
       //Con una interfaz que tomaras de otro lado seria mejor (por si cambiara uno de los dos)
       MiServicio cliente;
       if (servicioDeleg == "A") 
           cliente = new MiAplicacion.srvDeleg_A.MiServicio();
       else
           cliente = new MiAplicacion.srvDeleg_B.MiServicio(); 
      //Aquí se instancia el servicio para consumirlo, sería algo así:
      var resultado = cliente.ElContratoQueSea().....
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Creo que el problema ya estaba resuelto, el OP se había hecho bolas con validaciones en el constructor que no debieron estar ahí.

Comment: Eso mismo le dije en los comentarios @Flxtr, pero como parecia perdido agregue lo mismo como respuesta..

Comment: Hola. Eso no lo puedo hacer. Al declarar 'MiServicio cliente;' hay ambiguedad entre MiAplicacion.srvDeleg_A y MiAplicacion.srvDeleg_B, y este es el porqué de mi pregunta. Sí que se podría poner un If/else y en función del parámetro y repetir el código, instanciación incluida, en cada bloque, pero busco una solución más elegante que repetir el mismo código dos veces.